# Restore files to a previous version Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, restore

How can I restore files I've recently modified in Windows 7 if I haven't setup the back up feature or created one myself? to a prior state, perhaps a couple of days ago. If that's possible. Maybe a third party application?

Thank you

Comment: Which "files"? System updates? Installed applications? Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Windows 7 "Restore previous version" feature. [Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/recover-lost-or-deleted-files) is a detailled description and a video how to do that. In short it is right clicking the file and selecting "Restore previous version..." or opening the file/folders properties and going to the "previous version" tab.

But: restore previous version is not available for all files.

Comment: Yeah, that only works if I had set up the Back up feature prior to attempting restore files/folders. I specifically mentioned if I could NOT having the backup featured enabled.

Comment: @Oily "Restore previous version" does not require backups. It also works when the system sets a system restore point - which is done when doing windows updates or certain other installations. Did you check the link/procedure I wrote?

Comment: yeah, that only works if i have set up a restore point.